# Update a specific field for each document based on a function

Tags: python, pymongo

I have ~10k documents in my collection, with 3 fields`(name, wait, utc)`.

The timestamps are too granular for my use, and I want to round them down to the last 10 minutes.

I created a function to modify these timestamps (I am rounding them via a function called `round_to_10min()`, which I import from another python file I have called `utility_func.py`).

It's not slick or anything but it works:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def round_to_10min(my_dt):
  hours = my_dt.hour
  minutes =(my_dt.minute//10)*10
  date = dt(my_dt.year,my_dt.month,my_dt.day)  
  return dt(date.year, date.month,date.day, hours, minutes)
```

Is there a way for me to update the 'utc' field for each document in my collection, without taking the cursor and saving it into a list, iterating through it?

An example of what I would like to avoid having to do(doesn't seem efficient):

```
alldocs = collection.find({})
for x in alldocs:
  id = x['_id']
  old_value = int(x['utc'])
  new_value = utility_func.round_to_10min(old_value)
  update_val = {"$set":{"utc":new_value}}
  collection.update_one({"_id":ObjectId(id)},update_val)
```

Here's where I think I should be headed, but the update argument has me stumped...

```
update_value = {'$set':{'utc':result_from_function}}
collection.update_many({},update_value)
```

Is this achievable in pymongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanism you are seeking will not work.

Pymongo supports MongoDB operations only. If you can find a way to achieve your goal using MongoDB operations, you can perform this in a single update_many or aggregate query.

If you prefer to use python, then you're limited to your original approach of find, loop, update_one.